# How to send data to custom element setter method by Jquery?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, custom-element

I want to know, how to send data to a custom element by jquery. it is possible?.

I have a javascript vanilla code example over here, for understanding my question :

```js
// My custom element class
class MyCustomElementExample extends HTMLElement {
  set customData(data) {
    this._data = data;
    this.render();
  }

  render() {
    this.innerHTML = `<h1>${this._data.name}</h1>`;
  }
}

customElements.define('my-custom-element-example', MyCustomElementExample);

// select my custom element and send data to'customData'(setter method)
document.querySelector('my-custom-element-example').customData = {
  name: "DERI KURNIAWAN"
};
```

```html
<body>
  <my-custom-element-example></my-custom-element-example>
</body>
```

This is my specific javascript vanilla code for sending data to setter method :

```
document.querySelector('my-custom-element-example').customData = {name: "DERI KURNIAWAN"};
```

So is there a way to do that? or is there a special way? maybe if I think of the code like this:

```
$('my-custom-element-example').customData = {name: "DERI KURNIAWAN"};
```

Answer (score -1):

`document.querySelector('my-custom-element-example')`

and

`$('my-custom-element-example')`

Do exactly the same: retrieve a reference to a DOM element

But the jQuery version requires loading a 50KB+ library

jQuery was great in the age when all Browsers behaved different.

`.querySelector` and `.querySelectorAll` are the JavaScript standards;

IE9 was the last browser to implement these standards... **in 2011**

Comment: ok, good information. but is there still no way to send data to a custom element using jquery I mean? if available, I want to know the syntax

Comment: Your jQuery ``$(..)`` sends data.. provided you have loaded that 50KB+ jQuery library

Comment: but your answer is not what my question is

Comment: I interpreted your question as: _"How can I send data to a Web Component?"_